# Remove inches from rows in pandas dataframe with regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I'm trying to separate inches from product descriptions into a size column.

They can appear in any of these formats:

```
1"
1 1/2"
1.5"
1/2"
```

`pattern = r'\d+\s*\d*/*\d*\.\d*"'`

But it isn't working...

I have also tried `r'\d+\s*\d*/*\d*\.\d*\"'` with the added \ before the " to escape but this also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `(?:\d+\.?\d*|(?:\d+ )?\d+/\d+)\"`

```
(?:              # start group
\d+\.?\d*        # match a int/float-like
|                # or
(?:\d+ )?\d+/\d+ # match "a b/c" with optional "a "
)                # end group
\"               # followed by "
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UrYtFw/1)